# Object with Modifiers always shaded smooth and not flat

Tags: 3d-view

In my example I am having a simple path and using Screw and subsequently Solidify modifier. I cannot display it shaded flat. (Object > Shade Flat). See Screenshot.

When I convert the object into a Mesh it is still "shaded smooth", but at least I can change it to flat (Object on the right in Screenshot). For the object with modifiers I cannot.

I hate the "smooth shading" when using Modifiers. I could activate "Wireframe" in the Object Properties via "Viewport Display". But that is only a bad workaround I don't like.

P.S.: On a different note, it is very confusing that there is an Option Object > Shade Smooth/Shade Flat which cannot be found anywhere in the Properties of the object (or maybe I didn't find it?). Why is Blender doing it this way? Seems very inconsistent.
[image]

Comment: Hi :). To answer your sub-question: shading is applied *per polygon*, so it can't be an 'object property'. One object can have differently shaded areas ;)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The screw modifier itself has a setting under *Normals* to change whether it shades smooth.  Clear it and you won't get any smooth shading from the screw modifier.

The solidify modifier does not change the shading.

[image: screw modifier highlighting the shade smooth option]

Comment: Thanks! I am stupid. I looked everywhere but not there :(
Didn't imagine a modifier would add something like this.

Comment: @Shoe Off Head, if the answer is good, mark it as such  :)

Comment: Sorry for the delay. Thanks again.

Comment: @ShoeOffHead No problem.  StackExchange is different than other social media and takes getting used to.  You'll do fine here.